# É possível armazenar arquivos num executável?

Tags: c#, memória, assembly, reflexão, armazenamento

Preciso armazenar um arquivo, não importa sua extensão (é principalmente um Executável) dentro de um outro executável.

É que assim, estou compilando com *CodeDom* um executável que dentro do mesmo há um arquivo "especial" e encriptado, ao executar o executável toda mágica é feita. Mas o problema dessa mágica, é a maneira que estou guardando os `bytes` do arquivo mágico **m** dentro do executável **x**.

Quero colocar os bytes do arquivo **m** dentro do arquivo **x** de maneira literal.

Eu fiz o seguinte, no pré-compiler, fiz um método **estático** que já retorna automaticamente os bytes do arquivo **m**, mas para ter feito isso, foi necessário inserir **byte por byte** dentro do código, fiz uma gambiarra enorme para fazer isso, mas deu certo. Por exemplo, escrevi um programa de *Hello World* em C# e peguei os bytes deste arquivo e compilei dentro de outro executável, tipo um contêiner de arquivos.

Quando decompilei o executável de saída, obtive uma lista enorme de bytes encriptados, e não sei se isso é uma boa prática. Segue a imagem de como ficou:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ficou algo meio constante, não?

## Resumo da pergunta

Gostaria de saber, se há alguma maneira de implementar bytes de um arquivo sem usar valores literais, ou de não declarar uma variável para guardar enormes quantias de bytes, como fiz no exemplo acima.

Se não for possível fazer isso, essas listas têm limites de quantos bytes posso colocar nelas?

> Para ter uma ideia, aquele método retornava cerca de 200MB.

Comment: Curiosidade: Pq quer embarcar um arquivo dentro de um executavel? Qual problema está querendo resolver com isso?

Comment: Estou criando um meio de colocar um executável encriptado dentro do recipiente executável, ao executar o arquivo, o executável original é decriptado e é executado. É uma estratégia de contornar decompile.

Comment: Mas para isso existe a técnica de ofuscação. Não atende?

Comment: Não exatamente. Pois preciso criar uma instância do assembly recipiente.

Answer (score 1):

O que voce está tentando fazer se chama "EXE packer". Há muitas formas de fazer isto.
Veja esta ferramenta: [Inject your code to a Portable Executable file](http://www.ntcore.com/files/inject2exe.htm)
Estes são em C#:
[friedkiwi/netcrypt](https://github.com/friedkiwi/netcrypt)
[Vitevic Assembly Embedder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vitevic.VitevicAssemblyEmbedder)
[How to Write a Simple Packer/Unpacker with a Self-Extractor (SFX)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5035/How-to-Write-a-Simple-Packer-Unpacker-with-a-Self)
[UPX is a free, portable, extendable, high-performance executable packer for several executable formats.](https://upx.github.io/)
[C# Reversing - Unpacking A Packer [Part 2] - Reverse Engineering](http://0x00sec.org/t/c-reversing-unpacking-a-packer-part-2/1219)
Conforme observado, veja se esta lib lhe ajuda:
[C# File Resource Management Library](https://github.com/resourcelib/resourcelib)

Comment: Eu não quero exatamente fazer um packer de arquivos, e sim armazenar somente os bytes de um, mas de uma maneira que não seja necessário criar código literal para isso.